# limit row in join table with laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I got 2 tables in my DB (items and items_photos) I want to take rows from "items" table and join to item_photos (using items.id = items_photos.itemsId) but I want to get only one row from the item_photos tables to show paginated in as a search result, i.e:

```
items:
id    |    name    |    price    |    
------------------------------------------
1     |  item 1    |    30       |  
2     |  item 2    |    32       |
3     |  item 3    |    28       |


item_photos:
id    |    idItem  |    filename        |    
------------------------------------------
1     |      1     |    filename1.jpg   |  
2     |      1     |    filename2.jpg   |
3     |      1     |    filename3.jpg   |
4     |      2     |    filename4.jpg   |  
5     |      2     |    filename5.jpg   |
6     |      3     |    filename6.jpg   |
```

the result I want to get is:

```
  item.id  |  items.name  | items.price  |  photos.id  |  photos.filename
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1    |    item 1    |      30      |      1      |    filename1.jpg 
      2    |    item 2    |      30      |      4      |    filename4.jpg 
      3    |    item 3    |      30      |      6      |    filename6.jpg
```

what I tried is this

```
$result = Item::where('name', 'like', "%$query%")
                -join('item_photos', 'items.id', '=', 'item_photos.idItem')
                ->take(1)
                ->paginate(5);
```

but the result I get from this query shows repeated rows:

```
  item.id  |  items.name  | items.price  |  photos.id  |  photos.filename
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1    |    item 1    |      30      |      1      |    filename1.jpg 
      1    |    item 1    |      30      |      2      |    filename2.jpg
      1    |    item 1    |      30      |      3      |    filename3.jpg
      2    |    item 2    |      30      |      4      |    filename4.jpg   
      2    |    item 2    |      30      |      5      |    filename5.jpg 
      3    |    item 3    |      30      |      6      |    filename6.jpg
```

Comment: $result = Item::where('name', 'like', "%$query%")
                ->join('item_photos', 'items.id', '=', 'item_photos.idItem')->groupBy('item.id')
                ->take(1)
                ->paginate(5); try this one

Comment: thanks it worked, but i needed to config the database driver with "'strict' => false"